# como guardar una accion de jquery en el localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Pasa que tengo un botón que cuando le doy clic cambia el fondo a otro color y lo que quisiera es que se guardara en el `localStorage`. Así, cada vez que entren a la web, sea el color que eligió. Me explico:

```
function temas(){
$('#tema1').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background','#212121');
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues ya solo era complementar con lo de ***edgardo001***

```
function temas(){ 
  $('#tema1').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background','#212121');

    //Guardalo
    window.localStorage.setItem('background', '#212121');
  });
}
```

y ya en otra parte lo recuperas

```
if( window.localStorage.getItem('background') !== undefined){
    $('body').css('background', window.localStorage.getItem('background') );
}
```

y es todo :)

====

https://blog.elporfirio.com

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto te puede servir:

```
//Configura un localStorage  
 localStorage.setItem("Nombre", "tuNombre");
 //Obtiene un localStage   
 var nombre = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que no se como aplicarlo con la función que deje arriba colega

Answer (score 0):

No se a que te refieres con un localstage....pero podrias usar cookies para almacenar el color en el lado del cliente... Te dejo un link que te podría ser útil.... http://lineadecodigo.com/jquery/usando-cookies-con-jquery/

```
//Para acceder a una cookie
var texto = $.cookie('nombre_cookie');
//Para setear una cookie
$.cookie('nombre_cookie','valor');
```